# iOS - display PDF in a different Orientation

Tags: ios, pdf, uiview, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm using the following code to display a PDF inside a UIView

Its a simple application, displaying a single PDF (which is all I need) and I"m handling zooming separately: The problem I'm having with this is when the iPad changes to Landscape everything is distorted - any help as to where I should look ? / what i should do to handle the orientation issue ?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//PDF might be transparent, assume white paper - set White Background
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);

//Flip coordinates
CGContextGetCTM(ctx);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -rect.size.height);

//PDF File Path
NSURL *pdfURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TEST" withExtension:@"pdf"];
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfURL);
CGPDFPageRef page1 = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);

//Get the rectangle of the cropped inside
CGRect mediaRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page1, kCGPDFCropBox);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, rect.size.width / mediaRect.size.width,
                  rect.size.height / mediaRect.size.height);

//Draw PDF
CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page1);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi For Anybody Who may be interested in this. . .

This may be the best way to do it :
[Supporting two orientations with separate view controllers in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624910/supporting-two-orientations-with-separate-view-controllers-in-ios/18596471#18596471)

The following question discusses how to register to device orientation change, When a change in orientation is detected, a modal View is pushed -displaying the PDF with dimensions

The Other options may be as follows : when you initialize the UIView decide how you want it to react when the orientation changes

```
UIView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Play around with the various UIViewContentMode... : to achieve the best effect for you
The current one allows the PDF to be redrawn maintaining its Aspect ration and filling the entire size of the screen:so it cuts of about half the PDF - - -